# nested while loops in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to open `file-a` and set each line as a regex.

The number of times this regex occurs in `file-b` needs to be counted.

I'm doing this by pushing each match of the regex in `file-b` into an array `@matches`.

I then use `scalar(@matches)` to get the number of matches and print it to the screen.

I'm trying to do this using nested `while` loops and it isn't working.

What happens is that it also pushes the next regex (i.e. the next `$line` from `file-a`) into `@matches` instead of emptying`@matches`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $domains = "domainer.txt";
my $input   = "final_names.txt";
my @matches;
my $match;

open NAMES, $input or die "Can't open $input, Perl says $!\n";

while ( my $line = <NAMES> ) {
  chomp $line;

  my $id = $line;
  $id =~ s/\s//g;

  my $regex = $id;

  open DOMAINS, $domains or die "Can't open $domains, Perl says $!\n";

  while ( my $line = <DOMAINS> ) {

    if ($line =~ m/$regex/i) {
      push (@matches, $1);
    }

    $match = scalar (@matches);
    print "$match\n";
  }
}

close DOMAINS;
close NAMES;
```

Comment: "and it aint working" - please elaborate.

Comment: Note that you are opening DOMAINS file on every line and don't close it - it will create huge file descriptor leak. Expect your program to crash if NAMES contains more than few hundred lines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

figured it out - I needed to empty @matches using

```
undef @array;
```

after print statement

Comment: The goal is to count the number of entries for each $regex

Comment: Please don't. Move `my @array` into the outer loop instead.

Comment: You'll also need to move the `print` statement out of the inner loop.

Comment: Whatever your question may mean, this is the wrong solution. I have flagged this thread as being unhelpful and I hope it is deleted in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You need capturing parens.  Change:

```
  if ($line =~ m/$regex/i) {
```

to:

```
  if ($line =~ m/($regex)/i) {
```